# Update state from child component and return component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update a parent component from its child and return a component
here is what I'm doing:

```
const Template = () => {
    const [someVar, setSomeVar] = useState({a:"a"});
    const components = [];
    components.push(getComp(someVar, (vari) =>setSomeVar(vari), 1));
    return <div>{components}</div>;
};

const getComp = (someVar, updateVar, i) => {
    const someOtherVar = {...someVar, i: i};
    updateVar(someOtherVar);
    return <Typography key={i}> i </Typography>
};

export default Template;
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

I understand it's something to do with my setSomevar, but I'm boxing it, so it won't be triggered.

any thoughts?

Comment: You don't want to keep your components in the `components` const

Comment: why not? this is an exmaple, but my end goal is to create dynamic number of components in run time, is there other way to achieve it? and I still like to understand why I'm getting this error though

Comment: Keep number of components in state and then render template based on that state. React is data-driven

Comment: `someVar` is being updated in `getComp`. `getComp` is being run based on `someVar`. Isn't it endless render loop?

Comment: thanks, I'll keep that in mind. but it's still doesn't solve my issue, I'll have to update this state from a child component.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the **Template()** function in an infinite loop. Using the react hook the component is rerendered each time you call **setSomeVar**, which you do in the **getComp**  function automatically. Try adding your component on an event, like a clickEvent.

```
const Template = () => {
    const [components, addComponent] = useState([]);
    const click = (event) =>{
       const component = (<p>I'm a component!!</p>);
        addComponent([...components, component])
    }

    return <div><button onClick={click}>click me</button>
    {components.map(c => return c; )}</div>;
    };


export default Template;
```

Comment: The whole thing here is in a single component. but the logic in the main component rests the same. Keep in mind that you can't call the function updating the state directly, it will create an infinite loop.